# The textview is not stable in custom listview android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

actually I Have a custom listview which contains a countdown timer and the countdown timer is created by a handler, now the list loads fine and everything seems to be correct  but when I start to scroll the countdown timer becomes shaky and unstable the values seems to overlap each other means the lastrow values are printed in the first row and things like that, the values are up and down and it does not work properly, here the API sends a long value which is passed to handler and the handler converts that to a countdown timer, so where does the problem lies , whenever I refresh the list it becomes all fine, but as I start scrolling the same problem comes again.. here is my code

```
public class fixtures extends Fragment {

 private ListView fixtureListView;
 String Balance,userEmail;
 SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
 private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
 List<ListView_fixture_conveyer> fixture_conveyerList;
 ListView_fixture_conveyer fixtureList;


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fixtures, viewGroup, false);
    fixtureListView = view.findViewById(R.id.fixture_list);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);
    User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getUser();
    userEmail= user.getEmail();
    new JSONTask().execute("http://www.judgement6.com/judgement_files/fixture_json.php");


    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()

            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)

            .build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()))
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
            .build();
          com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);


    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            fixture_conveyerList.clear();
            new JSONTask().execute("http://www.judgement6.com/judgement_files/fixture_json.php");

            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    return view;
}


@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<ListView_fixture_conveyer>> {

    ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "loading,please wait...", null, true, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ListView_fixture_conveyer> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }


            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("list");
            fixture_conveyerList = new ArrayList<ListView_fixture_conveyer>();

            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.e("fixtureObject",finalObject.toString());
                fixtureList = new ListView_fixture_conveyer();
                fixtureList.setTournament(finalObject.getString("tournament"));
                fixtureList.setTeam1_photo(finalObject.getString("team1_photo"));
                fixtureList.setTeam2_photo(finalObject.getString("team2_photo"));
                fixtureList.setTeam1_name(finalObject.getString("team1_name"));
                fixtureList.setTeam2_name(finalObject.getString("team2_name"));
                fixtureList.setTime(finalObject.getString("Time"));
                fixture_conveyerList.add(fixtureList);
            }

            return fixture_conveyerList;

        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ListView_fixture_conveyer> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result !=null) {
            loading.dismiss();
            ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_list_fixture, result);
            fixtureListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            loading.dismiss();
        }

}
  }

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<ListView_fixture_conveyer> fixture_conveyerList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ListView_fixture_conveyer> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        fixture_conveyerList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        }

        final TextView team1_name,team2_name;
        final TextView tournament,time;
        ImageView team1_photo,team2_photo;

        team1_photo =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.team1);
        team2_photo =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.team2);
        team1_name =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.team1_name);
        team2_name =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.team2_name);
        tournament= convertView.findViewById(R.id.tournament);
        time= convertView.findViewById(R.id.timecounter);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTeam1_photo(), team1_photo);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTeam2_photo(), team2_photo);

        team1_name.setText(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTeam1_name());
        team2_name.setText(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTeam2_name());
        tournament.setText(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTournament());
        time.setText(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTime());

        Log.e("mytimer",fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTime());

        if (!("false").equals(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTime())){
            Log.e("inside_mytimer",fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTime());

        long newValue=Long.parseLong(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTime());
        new CountDownTimer(newValue, 1000) {

            @SuppressLint({"DefaultLocale", "SetTextI18n"})
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                time.setText("" + String.format(FORMAT,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                time.setText("Fixture closed");
            }
        }.start();
        }
        else{
            time.setText("Fixture closed");
        }


        return convertView;
    }
    }
 }
```

Here is my model class code

```
public class ListView_fixture_conveyer {

private String tournament;
private String team1_photo;
private String team2_photo;
private String team1_name;
private String team2_name;
private String time;

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}



public String getTeam1_name() {
    return team1_name;
}

public void setTeam1_name(String team1_name) {
    this.team1_name = team1_name;
}

public String getTeam2_name() {
    return team2_name;
}

public void setTeam2_name(String team2_name) {
    this.team2_name = team2_name;
}


public String getTournament() {
    return tournament;
}

public void setTournament(String tournament) {
    this.tournament = tournament;
}



public String getTeam1_photo() {
    return team1_photo;
}

public void setTeam1_photo(String team1_photo) {
    this.team1_photo = team1_photo;
}

public String getTeam2_photo() {
    return team2_photo;
}

public void setTeam2_photo(String team2_photo) {
    this.team2_photo = team2_photo;
}

}
```

Comment: its better to use RecylerView

Comment: Ok but pls help me with this now as I can't change it in this project

Comment: use Holder Pattern.

Comment: How I never used that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**  **(Tested)**

---> For Timer issue , you need to take time variable in your class and update variable **with Handler** use it with reload data. Like,

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         for (int i = 0, dataLength = fixture_conveyerList.size(); i < dataLength; i++) {
               ListView_fixture_conveyer item = fixture_conveyerList.get(i);
               item.timeRemaining -= 1000;
         }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000); //run every Second

    }
};
```

**List Adapter Class**

```
  public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<ListView_fixture_conveyer> fixture_conveyerList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewHolder holder;

    ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ListView_fixture_conveyer> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        fixture_conveyerList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 50);   //start unique timer

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.team1_photo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.team1);
            holder.team2_photo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.team2);
            holder.team1_name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.team1_name);
            holder.team2_name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.team2_name);
            holder.tournament = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tournament);
            holder.time = convertView.findViewById(R.id.timecounter);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTeam1_photo(), holder.team1_photo);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTeam2_photo(), holder.team2_photo);
        holder.team1_name.setText(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTeam1_name());
        holder.team2_name.setText(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTeam2_name());
        holder.tournament.setText(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTournament());
        holder.time.setText(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).timeRemaining);

        Log.e("mytimer", fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTime());

        if (!("false").equals(fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTime())) {
            Log.e("inside_mytimer", fixture_conveyerList.get(position).getTime());

            long newValue = fixture_conveyerList.get(position).timeRemaining;
         if (newValue > 0) {

            holder.time.setText(String.format(FORMAT,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(newValue),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(newValue) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(newValue)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(newValue) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(newValue))));
        } else {
           holder.time.setText("Fixture closed");
        }



        } else {
            holder.time.setText("Fixture closed");
        }


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: All the timer except the last one disappeared, it is only printing raw values which is coming from the API itself and the last one also shakes when I scroll the list

Comment: where do you define timeRemaining??

Comment: where do i add that handler which would make the timer??@Abhay Koradiya

Comment: do i need to add it in my model class or something??can you check my model clas s and tell me specifically.

Comment: How, I mean exactly

Comment: add `timeRemaining` field in model class.

Comment: I can add one integer and generate setter and getter for that but that is not working, actually I did not understood your point

Comment: Well I have added my model class could you elaborate

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting it somehow because from where would it get the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180424/discussion-between-abhay-koradiya-and-vipul-singh).

Comment: check my recent answer. It's Working and tested by me.

Comment: Ok, let me check it